# ForEach-Object Delete & Out-File

Tags: windows, powershell, get-childitem, foreach-object

I'm having trouble with one of my file deletion scripts on my directories.

I use `Get-ChildItem` to get the different files I want and I delete them with a `del`.
I would then like to keep logs of the deleted files with an `Out-File`.
However the `Out-file` does not work and the log file is empty.
The files are well deleted.

Here is my code, does anyone have any idea how I can solve my problem?

```bash
#5th directory
$Folder5 = "E:\What\Ever"
#delete
Get-ChildItem $Folder5 -Recurse -Force -ea 0 | Where-Object {
    $_.psiscontainer -and $_.fullname -notmatch 'coolfiles' -and 
    $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)
} | Select-Object -expandproperty FullName | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | del -Force -Recurse
    $_.FullName | Out-File "C:\What\Ever\deleteditems.txt" -encoding ASCII -Append
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: You have already expanded the `FullName` property from your `$_` hence when you do `$_.FullName` is actually `$null`, should be just `$_` instead.

Comment: You're also missing your `Where-Object` cmdlet.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala yes mb, copy paste problem, it appears in the script